# Запуск скриптов

Tags: jquery

У меня получался очень большой список `css файлов`, и я решил добавлять их в `head` используя `append`. Решение очень спорное, но для моего проекта самое то.

```
var list_style = [
    {style: 'css/style'},
    {style: 'css/animation'},
    {style: 'css/old'}
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < list_style.length; i++) {
        $("head").append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + list_style[i].style + '.css">');
    }
});
```

Сейчас хотел попробовать провернуть это со списком `jquery`. Но `append` предсказуемо просто добавляет `html код` с подключением скриптов. Есть возможность их как-то запустить? Они находят внизу `body`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, что такое "список `jquery`".

```js
let s = document.createElement("script");
s.textContent = "console.log('test s');";
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

```js
console.log("before", window.$);
let s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

```html
<button onclick="console.log('click', window.$)">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Массив заголовков скриптов

Comment: @Vanya Что такое "заголовки скриптов"?

Comment: Названия файлов

Comment: @Vanya Смотрите второй пример в ответе.

Comment: Большое спасибо. То что нужно

Comment: @Vanya Пожалуйста. Успехов.